# Why is this regular expression not matching?

Tags: regex

Could someone tell me why this regular expression does not match the below string? How could the regex be tweaked so it could match? The strings '`470123023`' and '`11-03-2015`' need to be in the regex...

```
.*-11-03-2015-.*_470123023_.*_META\.xml
```

wehansen-11-03-2015-09-35-12_470123023_META.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not matching because it needs at least two underscore `_` (just before META)

```
.*-11-03-2015-.*_470123023_.*_META\.xml
                          ^  ^
                          |  |
                         here is the issue
```

You should replace this

```
 .... 3_.*_META ....
```

with something like

```
 .... 3.*_META ....
```

Comment: that was the issue, sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

You have extra underscore and `.*` before `META`, try this regex:

```
.*-11-03-2015-.*_470123023_META\.xml
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW4jC7/1)